# Passing a string inside className in Next.js 13

Tags: typescript, next.js

Short and sweet. Im trying to generate radio buttons based on a list of strings in Next.js. The buttons are composed of an input tag and a label tag that use tailwind css to change behavior when checked by using the `peer/identifier` classname. I want to pass the string from the list inside the className string. How do I do that? Here is my attempt.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Some Radio Buttons</legend>
    {names.map((name: string) => (
        <>
            <input id={name} className="peer/{name} appearance-none absolute h-0 w-0 opacity-0" type="radio"/>
            <label htmlFor={name} className={"rounded-button peer-checked/{name}:bg-indigo-500"}>
                <span>{name}</span>
            </label>
        </>
    ))}


</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Tailwind can handle dynamically created `peer-*` class names. With that being said, a simple workaround would be to wrap each input + label combo in a div or span, and just use `peer` class names.

```js
<fieldset>
  <legend>Some Radio Buttons</legend>
  {names.map((name: string) => (
    <span key={name}>
      <input
        id={name}
        type="radio"
        name="names"
        className="peer appearance-none absolute h-0 w-0 opacity-0"
      />
      <label htmlFor={name} className="rounded-button peer-checked:bg-indigo-500">
        {name}
      </label>
    </span>
  ))}
</fieldset>
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Top Notch Code there! Yes, it works. Have a question about name="names". What does it do?

Comment: Defines radio group instead of individual radio buttons.